# Why does counting lines of csvfile in Python's csv.DictReader break my code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, dictionary

This feels like a stupid mistake, but I am unable to spot it. When I execute this code:

```
with open('test.csv') as csvfile:
    # row_count = sum(1 for row in csvfile)
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter = ';')
    path = os.getcwd()      # ← gets current directory

    for row in reader:
        header = row['FirstName'] + ' ' + row['Surname'] + ' – #' + row['RecruitmentID'].zfill(5)
        print('Processing: ' + ' / ' + header)
```

what I get is:

```
Processing:  / AAA aaa – #00005
Processing:  / BBB bbb – #00008
Processing:  / CCC ccc – #00160
[Finished in 0.3s]
```

But when I uncomment `# row_count = sum(1 for row in csvfile)` I only get `[Finished in 0.3s]` in the console.

Even using another method: `numberofrows = len(list(reader))` instead breaks it the same way. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: while doing `row_count = sum(1 for row in csvfile)` you go to the end of your file , this way the csv reader won't fine anything else, try doing  `csvfile.seek(0)`, that should take you back at the beginning of the file, before creating the csv reader

Comment: @LohmarASHAR oh, this was it! Thanks, I am new to working with streams and files…

Comment: Offtopic: when you ask a question and write some example code, make it as minimal as possible. Importing `pypdftk` or `path = os.getcwd()` makes other users read too much code (and think about it) that has nothing to do with your question. Thank you.

Comment: @eumiro perhaps you are right, but I wasn't completely unaware which part was causing this behavior. Editer for clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will read the entire CSV file:

```py
row_count = sum(1 for row in csvfile)
```

When you read a file in Python (or any other language) you are moving the "position" in the file. When you finish reading the file, the position is remembered as the end of the file. There's just nothing left to read.

Either you can close and re-open the file, or you can "rewind"/"seek" the position back to the start of the file.

This is done with the following code:

```py
csvfile.seek(0, os.SEEK_SET)
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining this to me. I don't see how `csvfile.seek(0, os.SEEK_SET)` is any different from csvfile.seek(0) in terms of my program's behavior.

Comment: You're right, they're the same thing.

From the [official documentation about file I/O](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html?highlight=seek): "To change the file object’s position, use `f.seek(offset, from_what).`"

`from_what` is optional but has values 0 ("from the start of the file"), 1 ("from the current position"), and 2 ("from the end of the file"). Just giving `csvfile.seek(0)` defaults to 0. `os.SEEK_SET == 0` as well.

Answer (score 1):

`row_count = sum(1 for row in csvfile)` will read the whole file. When calling `for row in reader:` you are already at EOF.